# Apply a function to variables with a name pattern for each id with NA values

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I have a data table where I would like to calculate the mean of the group of variables starting with "amount" for each of the ids.

The number of variable starting with amount can vary, but they are well over 100 in my real data (and some variables have NA values).

```
id  variable    amountA amountB amountC amountD
1   A   8   7   6   2
2   B   6   2   1   2
3   C   6   6   9   4
4   D   1   6   2   7
```

In my data I have tried unsucessfully:

```
DT[,testvar := apply(DT[ ,grepl("amount",names(DT))],1,mean)]
DT[,testvar := mean(DT[ ,grepl("amount",names(DT))],na.rm=TRUE), by = idvar]
```

I'm trying to work it out with the .EACHI but I haven't figure it out yet. Any idea or comment hugely appreciated.

Sample table:

```
structure(list(id = 1:4, variable = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), amountA = c(8L, 6L, 6L, 1L
), amountB = c(7L, 2L, 6L, 6L), amountC = c(6L, 1L, 9L, 2L), 
    amountD = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 7L)), .Names = c("id", "variable", 
"amountA", "amountB", "amountC", "amountD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Check the [HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), especially the part on `.SD` and `.SDcols` from the `Introduction to data.table` vignette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution taking some of Arun's suggestions:

```
DT[, testvar:=rowMeans(.SD, na.rm=T), .SDcols=grep("^amount", names(DT), value=T)]
```

Produces:

```
   id variable amountA amountB amountC amountD testvar
1:  1        A       8       7       6       2    5.75
2:  2        B       6       2       1       2    2.75
3:  3        C       6       6       9       4    6.25
4:  4        D       1       6       2       7    4.00
```

We define what columns we want to be part of the internal `.SD` object with `.SDcols` and `grep`, and then we just `rowSums` the resulting `.SD`.

In more recent versions of `data.table` you can shortcut this by using `patterns` in `.SDcols`:

```
DT[, testvar := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = patterns('amount')]
```

Comment: @Arun, nice, though in this case we don't know the range of "amountXX".  You guys are adding so many features I feel like I get hopelessly obsolete on the DT cutting edge stuff all the time.

Comment: @Arun, OP states number of `AmountX` variables "can vary, but they are well over 100 in my real data"

Comment: @Arun, I was going to ask whether you were working something like `rowwise`, but then figured I should just check.  I realized about the coercion and resultant copy, but didn't want to delve into it in this answer.